# Using ng-repeat to provide multiple buttons

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to create a list of buttons with ng-repeat, each of which can be clicked to perform the same function, in this case, roll a die.  How do I get it so that each button has it's own unique reference to the results?  Currently when one button is clicked, the correct calculation is done, but the results are displayed next to every button, not just the button that was clicked.

Here is what I have so far [(***fiddle***)](http://jsfiddle.net/jgoemat/9ma7H/):

in html

```
...
<div ng-repeat="die in dice">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="rollDice(1, die, 0, scope)">{{"d" + die}}</button>
    <span>{{result}}</span>
</div>
...
```

in controller.js

```
angular.module('diceAngularApp')
.controller('DiceController', function ($scope) {

$scope.dice = [2,3,4,6,8,10,12,20,100];
$scope.result = 0;

$scope.rollDice = function(numRolls, numSides, bonus) {
  var total = "";
  var rolls = new Array( numRolls );

  for (var i = 0; i < numRolls; i++ ) {
    var roll = randomInt( 1, numSides );
    rolls[i] = roll;
    total += roll;      
  }

  $scope.result = total;
}

    function randomInt( intMin, intMax ) {
        intMax = Math.round( intMax );
        intMin = Math.round( intMin );
        return intMin + Math.floor( intMax * (Math.random() % 1));
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ng-repeat` creates a new child scope for each iteration, but the `$scope` variable in your `rollDice` method is the parent scope.  The easiest way would be to return the result from rollDice instead of setting a scope property directly and set that value in your ng-click [(***fiddle***)](http://jsfiddle.net/jgoemat/Gv9kV/):

```
ng-click="result = rollDice(1, die, 0)"
```

Another way would be to access the child scope by passing the `$event` variable and use angular.element($event.target).scope(): [(***fiddle***)](http://jsfiddle.net/jgoemat/byVN3/1/):

```
<div ng-repeat="die in dice">
    <button type="button"
        class="btn btn-default"
        ng-click="rollDice(1, die, 0, $event)"> <!-- pass $event -->
            {{"d" + die}}<br/>
    </button>
    <span>{{result}}</span>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$scope.rollDice = function(numRolls, numSides, bonus, $event) {
  var total = "";
  var rolls = new Array( numRolls );

  for (var i = 0; i < numRolls; i++ ) {
    var roll = randomInt( 1, numSides );
    rolls[i] = roll;
    total += roll;
  }

  // get scope for element sending event and use it
  angular.element($event.target).scope().result = total;
}
```

Yet another way would be to have an object on your child scope to hold the results and pass that object to your click function.  You can initialize the object with `ng-init` [(***fiddle***)](http://jsfiddle.net/jgoemat/Zs4RB/)

```
<div ng-repeat="die in dice">
    <button
        ng-init="results = { result: 0 }"
        type="button"
        class="btn btn-default"
        ng-click="rollDice(1, die, 0, results)">
            {{"d" + die}}<br/>
    </button>
    <span>{{results.result}}</span>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$scope.rollDice = function(numRolls, numSides, bonus, results) {
  var total = "";
  var rolls = new Array( numRolls );

  for (var i = 0; i < numRolls; i++ ) {
    var roll = randomInt( 1, numSides );
    rolls[i] = roll;
    total += roll;
  }

  results.result = total;
}
```

Comment: Oh wow, you went over and beyond on that one. I really like the first way you did it. I think that was sort of what I was trying to come up with, but had no idea how to do it.  

Is one of these considered better practice than the others?  I think I vaguely remember reading that using ng-init was considered bad practice as initialization code should be handled in the controller (please correct me if I'm wrong)

Also, I'm a little confused what the {{$scope|json}} is doing in the second one. It didn't seem to be doing anything in the fiddle and when I tried removing it, seemed to work just fine

Comment: @firexion `{{ $scope | json }}` is a [`filter`](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_09). As you have no "direct" control of the scope created by `ng-repeat` you need to use `ng-init` to set the scopes variable to the initial state for each dice.

Comment: I understand it's a filter and that it is used to filter the $scope into json format. I was just confused as to the purpose of it here. It didn't seem to be printing anything off and removing it didn't change anything, so I was just confused by it, sorry. Ah, that makes a lot of sense for ng-init, that really helps explain its usage. Thank you. :)

Comment: No purpose, I was thinking it might show the scope variables clearly but apparently not... I removed it.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `controller` for each of the `divs` surrounding the `button`, then they get their own `scope`.

**page.html**

```
...
<div ng-repeat="die in dices" ng-controller="DieCtrl">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="rollDice(1, die, 0, scope)">{{"d" + die}}</button>
    <span>{{result}}</span>
</div>
...
```

**controller.js**

```
app.controller('DieCtrl', function ($scope) {
    ...
});
```

Comment: Ah, that worked perfectly, I just had to move the calculation code into the DieCtrl and leave the setup stuff in the main DiceController and it works perfectly, thank you so much.